# Join Multiple table with multiple Group Concate Mysql

Tags: mysql, join, group-concat

I have 4 table that is

trxn_tbl:

```
works_id    works_date
1           3/17/2017
2           3/19/2017
3           3/18/2017
```

apps_txn_tbl:

```
id  works_id    apps_name
1   1            JoinBDApps
2   1            PMS
3   1            CADET COLLEGE
4   2            JoinBDApps
5   2            PMS
6   2            CADET COLLEGE
7   3            JoinBDApps
8   3            PMS
9   3            CMH
```

work_loc_trxn_tbl:

```
id  works_id    loc 
1   1           DC  
2   2           AITSO   
3   3           DR
```

works_type_txn_tbl:

```
    id  works_id  works_type
    1   1         Trobleshooting
    2   1         Software Upgrade
    3   2         Trobleshooting
    4   2         License Key Update
    5   3         Trobleshooting
    6   3         License Key Update
```

When i run query Mysql Said:
 MySQL said: Documentation

## 1055 - Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'dcapp_db.work_loc_txn_tbl.loc' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

But I want this type:

```
works_id    Works_date   work_type                            appsname                                       loc
1           3/17/2017   Trobleshooting, software upgrade    JoinBDapps, PMS, CADET COLLEGE                       DR
2           3/19/2017    Trobleshooting,  License Key Update    JoinBDapps, PMS, CADET COLLEGE                   AITSO
3           3/18/2017    Trobleshooting,  License Key Update     JoinBDApps, PMS,  CMH                           DR
```

Where is problem and Is i need to change the table system or query pleas help me....
My query is:"my query is:

```
SELECT trxn_tbl.works_id, trxn_tbl.works_date,work_loc_txn_tbl.loc,GROUP_CONCAT(works_type_txn_tbl.works_type SEPARATOR ',')as worktype,GROUP_CONCAT(apps_txn_tbl.apps_name SEPARATOR ',')as appname FROM trxn_tbl JOIN works_type_txn_tbl on works_type_txn_tbl.works_id=trxn_tbl.works_id JOIN apps_txn_tbl on apps_txn_tbl.works_id=trxn_tbl.works_id JOIN work_loc_txn_tbl on work_loc_txn_tbl.works_id=trxn_tbl.works_id GROUP BY trxn_tbl.works_id;
```

"

Answer (score 0):

1. works_id, works_date, loc needs to add into GROUP BY.
2. You have used two GROUP_CONCAT in one query, then this query has not
   enough columns to GROUP BY, so GROUP_CONCAT has duplicate
       contents.

Try this:

```
SELECT
    trxn_tbl.works_id,
    trxn_tbl.works_date,
    work_loc_txn_tbl.loc,
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        DISTINCT works_type_txn_tbl.works_type SEPARATOR ',' -- add DISTINCT
    ) AS worktype,
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        DISTINCT apps_txn_tbl.apps_name SEPARATOR ',' -- add DISTINCT
    ) AS appname
FROM
    trxn_tbl
INNER JOIN works_type_txn_tbl ON works_type_txn_tbl.works_id = trxn_tbl.works_id
INNER JOIN apps_txn_tbl ON apps_txn_tbl.works_id = trxn_tbl.works_id
INNER JOIN work_loc_txn_tbl ON work_loc_txn_tbl.works_id = trxn_tbl.works_id
GROUP BY
    trxn_tbl.works_id,
    trxn_tbl.works_date,
    work_loc_txn_tbl.loc
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7fd510/13)

Comment: Your suggestion is so helpful to me

Comment: Is it possible to add more group concat in my query? I need 6 or six group concate in one query... Is is possible?

Comment: I think it is impossible to have six group concate in one query, at least I don`t know how, Maybe there are some better sql queries can do that.;)

Comment: I found a new way to fix your problem that add DISTINCT in GROUP_CONCAT, and it works well with sample data, however, I am not sure if it works well with six group concate, or if it will have a bad performance with more data, I updated my sql query and try it again please.@ForkanAkon